# Portable serialization of data in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, c

Is there really no functions / macros in the Linux kernel for portable serialization of integers (and other data types) to byte arrays? I would think that this must be such a common use case. For clarity, I mean something like this:

```
u8 buffer[4];
s16 vals[2] = {2352, -234};
cpu_to_le_array(vals, ARRAY_SIZE(vals), buffer);
```

Implementing these sort of functions by hand is error prone. Surely there must be a standard and well tested way to do such serialization, ideally using a macro that checks the array length and data types...

I found this article which talks about portable conversions, but the listed macros / functions don't seem to be suitable for serialization: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5783